# nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000 After installing a new GPU

Tags: nvidia

After I enter my password the screen goes black for a really long time and then I get logged in. This first started happening when I swapped to a new GPU. Both GPUs were nvidia 2070. Here is the relevant output from dmesg:

```
[    4.396503] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input25
[    4.396554] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input26
[    4.396590] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input27
[    4.396626] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input28
[    4.472997] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    4.473007] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    4.473009] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
[    4.473018] ucsi_ccg: probe of 0-0008 failed with error -110
[    4.473077] kvm: disabled by bios
[    4.473091] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.473093] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.592850] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.592853] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.593168] kvm: disabled by bios
[    4.668497] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xab6b705c
[    4.696682] kvm: disabled by bios
[    4.696945] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.696946] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.805161] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.805163] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.805180] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    4.805202] kvm: disabled by bios
[    4.827383] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: start vif 70:66:55:0c:05:dd on port 0
[    4.940777] kvm: disabled by bios
[    4.941002] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.941004] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    5.234828] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    5.234930] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.0+0x73/0x80 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[    5.288578] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    5.288580] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    5.288994] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.528038] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[    5.692873] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.693058] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    5.693059] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    5.800865] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.801058] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    5.801060] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    6.080913] kvm: disabled by bios
[    6.081216] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    6.081217] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    6.200738] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    6.200739] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    6.201172] kvm: disabled by bios
[    6.308902] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    6.308904] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    6.309129] kvm: disabled by bios
[    6.420514] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    6.420515] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    7.324587] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[    7.432252] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
[    7.667842] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   13.752039] Bluetooth: hci1: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   16.853545] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.853550] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.853555] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   17.152021] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
[   17.312498] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   17.852012] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 39
[   17.920017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 2
[   20.804522] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   21.805019] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   22.806540] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   23.808015] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   24.809524] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   25.811039] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   26.812518] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   27.814035] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   28.815548] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   29.817017] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   30.818528] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   31.820019] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   32.821521] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   33.823034] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   34.824526] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   35.837669] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   36.851041] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   37.862911] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   38.873152] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   39.882630] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   40.891077] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   41.898663] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   42.905472] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   43.911630] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   44.917202] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   45.922239] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   47.177551] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   48.180689] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   49.184495] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   50.187005] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   51.190241] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   52.192282] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   53.308282] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   54.309944] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   55.311431] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   56.312822] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   57.314104] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   58.315287] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   59.316384] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   60.317405] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   61.920091] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   62.930979] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   63.941790] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   64.952563] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   65.963333] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   66.974034] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   67.984900] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   68.996935] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   70.247836] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   71.249773] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   72.251605] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   73.253382] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   74.283634] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   75.559567] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   76.562143] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   77.564665] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   78.567113] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   79.569537] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   80.571910] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   81.574215] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   82.576513] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   83.578735] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   84.580956] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   85.583143] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   86.585275] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   87.587399] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   88.589500] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   89.591542] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   90.593597] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   91.714170] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   92.765177] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   93.780646] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   94.796134] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   95.549446] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 1
[   95.673519] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 5
[   97.076402] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  105.469710] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4082.000C: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for missing that info, I use ubuntu 20.04, I tried both nvidia-driver-440 and 450. Kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Are Nvidia drivers installed? Which version?

Comment: Sorry for missing that info, I use uibuntu 20.04, I tried both nvidia-driver-440 and 450. Kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic

Comment: These messages are harmless. But it is a sort of a bug, that will be fixed sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the problem. It was not an issue with ubuntu itself rather with OpenRGB. I have a command in .profile to change the rgb lighing of the ram to white. However OpenRGB was taking a long time with my graphics card I'm guessing trying to detect any devices on it. My graphics card does not have rgb. I added a & to the end of the command so that I runs in the background. Now I log in immidiately and after a minute or so the rgb lights change.

Comment: Where can I write this command please

Comment: I too am having this same error (intermittently). I would like to discuss this with you in further detail. First I DO NOT have a command in .profile for OpenRGB to run. Could you provide the command? Secondly, when I get this error, I have found that my ARGB location is incorrect. It will randomly switch from /dev/hidraw4 to something completely random like /dev/hidraw(insert number here). Have you opened OpenRGB and checked the location and address of you i2c to see if it is randomly changing, or was this error constant and not intermitent like mine before you changed your command?

Comment: did you really wait 1 minute for it to start?